# Loki js query to database returns nothing

Tags: javascript, lokijs

I am trying to use loki js in order to filter the objects whose timestamps are older than current:

```
public getExpiredElements(): any[] {
let currentDate = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(currentDate);
return this.collectionName.chain().find(this.collection).where( (obj) => {
  console.log(obj.expirationTimeStamp);
  obj.expirationTimeStamp < currentDate;
}).data();
}
```

I get empty table though. Is my syntax correct?

Answer (score 0):

You must `return` your comparison in the `where` method.

`this.collectionName.chain().find(this.collection).where( (obj) => {
  return obj.expirationTimeStamp < currentDate;
})`